# Mailkit: Get time of read emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mailkit, mimekit

I save email files as .eml by Mailkit and want to show user when did read or open this email. 
is it possible by eml file or must save read date separately?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the user opens the .eml file, I guess you could check the access-time using `File.GetLastAccessTime()` of the file on the file system to see if it is different from the creation-time (by using `File.GetCreationTime()`). If it is, then that's probably the date & time that the user last read the .eml file, but that won't necessarily give you the date & time when the user *first* read the .eml file.

Comment: my problem is when user read email on other device and i want to get time of opening that email